# OpenCl: sample float4 program - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, floating-point, opencl

It is simple program that read two float4 vectors from files then calculate sum of opposite numbers.
I couldn't find the problem:
MAIN file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <time.h>
#endif



const int number_of_points = 16;  // number of points in Both  A and B files (number of rows)
const int number_of_axis = 4;     // number of points axis in Both  A and B files (number of Columns)


using namespace std;

void checkError(cl_int err, const char *operation)
{
  if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error during operation '%s': %d\n", operation, err);
    exit(1);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    clock_t tStart = clock();
    // Create the two input vectors
    // working variables
    int i;
    ifstream input_fileA, input_fileB;  // input files
    string line;    // transfer row from file to array
    float x;        // transfer word from file to array
    int row = 0;    // number of rows of file A,B (= array)
    int col = 0;    // number of rows of file A,B (= array)

    // working arrays

    // working arrays
//  int mem_size_TempA = number_of_points * number_of_axis * sizeof(cl_float);
//  int mem_size_TempB = number_of_points * number_of_axis * sizeof(cl_float);

    float tempAArray[number_of_points][number_of_axis]={{0}};   // array contains file A data
    float tempBArray[number_of_points][number_of_axis]={{0}};   // array contains file B data



    int mem_size_InputA = number_of_points * number_of_axis ;
    int mem_size_InputB = number_of_points * number_of_axis ;
    int mem_size_Output = number_of_points * number_of_axis ;

    float *inputAArray = (float*) malloc(number_of_points*sizeof(cl_float4));   // array contains file A data
    float *inputBArray = (float*) malloc(number_of_points*sizeof(cl_float4));   // array contains file B data
    float *outputArray = (float*) malloc(number_of_points*sizeof(cl_float4));   // array contains file B data


    // import input files
    input_fileA.open(argv[1]);
    input_fileB.open(argv[2]);


    // transfer input files data to array
    // input file A to arrayA
    row = 0;
    while (getline(input_fileA, line))
    {

        istringstream streamA(line);
        col = 0;
        while(streamA >> x){
            tempAArray[row][col] = x;
            col++;
        }
        row++;
    }

    // input file B to arrayB
    row = 0;
    while (getline(input_fileB, line))
    {

        istringstream streamB(line);
        col = 0;
        while(streamB >> x){
            tempBArray[row][col] = x;
            col++;
        }
        row++;
    }

    // switch columns of B array
    for(int row_of_arrayB = 0; row_of_arrayB < number_of_points; row_of_arrayB++ )
    {
        float temporary = tempBArray[row_of_arrayB][2];
        tempBArray[row_of_arrayB][2] = tempBArray[row_of_arrayB][1];
        tempBArray[row_of_arrayB][1] = temporary;
    }

    // from Array to 3d vectors
//    for (int row_of_array = 0; row_of_array<number_of_points; row_of_array++)
//    {
//      inputAArray[row_of_array] = (tempAArray[row_of_array][0], tempAArray[row_of_array][1], tempAArray[row_of_array][2],0);
//      inputBArray[row_of_array] = (tempBArray[row_of_array][0], tempBArray[row_of_array][1], tempBArray[row_of_array][2],0);
//    }

    for (int row_of_array=0; row_of_array < number_of_points; row_of_array++)
    {

        inputAArray[row_of_array*number_of_points+0] = tempAArray[row_of_array][0];
        inputAArray[row_of_array*number_of_points+1] = tempAArray[row_of_array][1];
        inputAArray[row_of_array*number_of_points+2] = tempAArray[row_of_array][2];
        inputAArray[row_of_array*number_of_points+3] = 0.0f;

        inputBArray[row_of_array*number_of_points+0] = tempBArray[row_of_array][0];
        inputBArray[row_of_array*number_of_points+1] = tempBArray[row_of_array][1];
        inputBArray[row_of_array*number_of_points+2] = tempBArray[row_of_array][2];
        inputBArray[row_of_array*number_of_points+3] = tempBArray[row_of_array][3];

        outputArray[row_of_array*number_of_points+0] = 0.0f;
        outputArray[row_of_array*number_of_points+1] = 0.0f;
        outputArray[row_of_array*number_of_points+2] = 0.0f;
        outputArray[row_of_array*number_of_points+3] = 0.0f;
//      inputBArray[row_of_array] = (tempBArray[row_of_array][0], tempBArray[row_of_array][1], tempBArray[row_of_array][2],0);

    }
//    for (int row_of_array=0; row_of_array < number_of_points; row_of_array++)
//    {
//      printf("0: %f, 1: %f, 2: %f, 3: %f \n", inputAArray[row_of_array*number_of_points+0], inputAArray[row_of_array*number_of_points+1],
//              inputAArray[row_of_array*number_of_points+2], inputAArray[row_of_array*number_of_points+3]);
//    }
    // close input files
    input_fileA.close();
    input_fileB.close();




    // Load the kernel source code into the array source_str
    FILE *fp;
    char *source_str;
    size_t source_size;

    fp = fopen("calculate_bottom_SNM_kernel.cl", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t programLength = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    source_str = (char*)malloc(programLength+1);
    source_size = fread( source_str, 1, programLength, fp);
    source_str[programLength] = '\0';
    fclose( fp );

    // Get platform and device information
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs( platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 1,
            &device_id, &ret_num_devices);

    // Create an OpenCL context
    cl_context context = clCreateContext( NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);

    // Create a command queue
    cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);

    // Create memory buffers on the device for each vector
    cl_mem inputa_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
            mem_size_InputA*sizeof(cl_float4) , NULL, &ret);
    cl_mem inputb_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
            mem_size_InputB*sizeof(cl_float4), NULL, &ret);

    cl_mem output_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
            mem_size_Output*sizeof(cl_float4), NULL, &ret);


    // Copy the lists A and B to their respective memory buffers
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, inputa_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
            mem_size_InputA*sizeof(cl_float4), inputAArray, 0, NULL, NULL);
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, inputb_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
            mem_size_InputB*sizeof(cl_float4), inputBArray, 0, NULL, NULL);


    // Create a program from the kernel source
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1,
            (const char **)&source_str, (const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);

    // Build the program

    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret == CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE)
      {
        // Get size of build log
        size_t logSize;
        ret = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,
                                    0, NULL, &logSize);
        checkError(ret, "getting build log size");

        // Get build log
        char log[logSize];
        ret = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,
                                    logSize, log, NULL);
        checkError(ret, "getting build log");

        printf("OpenCL program build log:\n%s\n", log);
        exit(1);
      }


    // Create the OpenCL kernel
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "calculate_bottom_SNM", &ret);

    // Set the arguments of the kernel
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&inputa_mem_obj);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&inputb_mem_obj);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&output_mem_obj);

    // Execute the OpenCL kernel on the list
    size_t global_item_size = number_of_points; // Process the entire lists
    size_t local_item_size = 4; // Process in groups of 64

    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL,
            &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Read the memory buffer C on the device to the local variable C
//    int *C = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*number_of_points);


//    float *C = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*number_of_points);
    clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, output_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
            mem_size_Output, outputArray, 0, NULL, NULL);


    // Display the result to the screen
//    float buttomSNM = 0;
//    for(i = 0; i < number_of_points; i++)
//    {
//      for (int t=0; t<4; t++)
//      {
//          cout << "h" ;
////            printf("%f, \n", outputArray[i*number_of_points+t]);
//      }
//  }

    // Clean up
    ret = clFlush(command_queue);
    ret = clFinish(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(inputa_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(inputb_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(output_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseContext(context);
    free (inputAArray);
    free (inputBArray);
    free (outputArray);
printf("ALL Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

Kernel:

```
__kernel void calculate_bottom_SNM(__global float4 *inputAArray, __global float4 *inputBArray,
                         __global float4 *outputArray) {

    // Get the index of the current element
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    int number_of_points = 16;


    outputArray[i*number_of_points+0] = inputAArray[i*number_of_points+0] + inputBArray[i*number_of_points+0];
    outputArray[i*number_of_points+1] = inputAArray[i*number_of_points+1] + inputBArray[i*number_of_points+1];
    outputArray[i*number_of_points+2] = inputAArray[i*number_of_points+2] + inputBArray[i*number_of_points+2];
    outputArray[i*number_of_points+3] = inputAArray[i*number_of_points+3] + inputBArray[i*number_of_points+3];


}
```

The first input files: A.txt

```
0   0.000000e+00    9.998994e-01    
1   1.000000e-03    9.998981e-01    
2   2.000000e-03    9.998967e-01    
3   3.000000e-03    9.998953e-01    
4   4.000000e-03    9.998939e-01    
5   5.000000e-03    9.998925e-01    
6   6.000000e-03    9.998911e-01    
7   7.000000e-03    9.998896e-01    
8   8.000000e-03    9.998881e-01    
9   9.000000e-03    9.998865e-01    
10  1.000000e-02    9.998850e-01    
11  1.100000e-02    9.998834e-01    
12  1.200000e-02    9.998817e-01    
13  1.300000e-02    9.998800e-01    
14  1.400000e-02    9.998783e-01    
15  1.500000e-02    9.998766e-01
```

The second input file B:

```
0   0.000000e+00    9.998966e-01    
1   1.000000e-03    9.998953e-01    
2   2.000000e-03    9.998939e-01    
3   3.000000e-03    9.998925e-01    
4   4.000000e-03    9.998911e-01    
5   5.000000e-03    9.998896e-01    
6   6.000000e-03    9.998881e-01    
7   7.000000e-03    9.998866e-01    
8   8.000000e-03    9.998850e-01    
9   9.000000e-03    9.998834e-01    
10  1.000000e-02    9.998818e-01    
11  1.100000e-02    9.998801e-01    
12  1.200000e-02    9.998785e-01    
13  1.300000e-02    9.998767e-01    
14  1.400000e-02    9.998750e-01    
15  1.500000e-02    9.998732e-01
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are computing your array indices in your kernel in a fairly strange manner:

```
i*number_of_points+0
i*number_of_points+1
i*number_of_points+2
i*number_of_points+3
```

Think about what this actually translates to for different values of `i` (assuming `number_of_points=16`):

```
 i     array indices (i*16 + (0,1,2,3))
 --------------------------------------
 0     0,   1,  2,  3
 1     16, 17, 18, 19
 2     32, 33, 34, 35
 ...
 etc
```

This is surely not what you wanted! Your sample code appears to just be trying to perform a vectorised vector addition. If that's the case, your kernel code just needs to look something like this:

```
__kernel void vecadd(__global float4 *inputA,
                     __global float4 *inputB,
                     __global float4 *output)
{
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    output[i] = inputA[i] + inputB[i];
}
```

This works because were are performing the same operation to each element of the vector. If you have a kernel that needs to use these elements separately, you would write code like this:

```
float4 valueA = inputA[i];
float4 valueB = inputB[i];

float4 result;
result.x = valueA.x + valueB.x; // Do something with first component
result.y = valueA.y * valueB.y; // Do something with second component
result.z = valueA.z / valueB.z; // Do something with third component
result.w = valueA.w - valueB.w; // Do something with fourth component
```

Comment: Thanks @jprice, I did that but when I run it, 14 errors were found. The follow is last one:

"/tmp/OCL3559T1.cl", line 45: error: expression must have struct or union type
   outputArray.z = inputAArray.z / inputBArray.z; // Do something with third component
                                   ^

14 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/OCL3559T1.cl".

Frontend phase failed compilation.

Comment: you should not compile the CL file while you compile your app, thats the task of the runtime compiler.

Comment: @RamiAqqad It looks like you are trying to use `.z` on an array of vectors, rather than single vector type. Notice that in my code, I am loading a `float4` value from the array into a temporary, and then using `.x`, `.y` etc.

Comment: thanks @jprice , I fixed it but the results were unexpected I will post the new code in another question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389219/opencl-c-unexpected-results-of-simple-sum-float-vector-program